# Banishing cards from the graveyard

Tags: yu-gi-oh

What does it mean to banish a card from the grave yard? I have a card that says to banish a card from the graveyard and I don't know what it means.

Comment: Can you link what card you have with this effect? It might help us give a better, more understandable answer if we have some context to work with.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of zones on the yugioh board. If you look at [this playmat](http://orig14.deviantart.net/49b2/f/2014/258/6/f/yu_gi_oh__playmat_template_by_thaemperor2000-d7z99fh.jpg) (not currently up to date with the newest rules for link summons, but it's fine for this purpose), you can see that there is a "Banished Zone".

Now, this is not an official zone in Yugioh, since "banished" used to mean "removed from the game" and cards that are banished are supposed to be in "no particular zone". I will however refer to the place where you put banished cards as the "Banished Zone" for simplicity's sake.

**To "banish" a card from anywhere means to put the card from wherever it was before faceup into the "Banished Zone"**. Both players may look at their own or the opponent's face-up banished cards at any time. Each player has his own Banished Zone.

A card in the Banished Zone can usually not be accessed again, but there are some cards that allow you to get back your banished cards.

Cards that interact with banished cards (examples):

- [Kycoo, the Ghost Destroyer](https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/yugioh/images/0/06/KycootheGhostDestroyer-BP02-EN-C-1E.png/revision/latest?cb=20130712031237)
- [Necroface](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/yugioh/images/e/e2/Necroface-DPRP-EN-C-1E.png/revision/latest?cb=20160916161456)
- [D.D. Warrior Lady](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/yugioh/images/7/7b/DDWarriorLady-YS14-EN-C-1E.png/revision/latest?cb=20140711044446)
- [Breakthrough Skill](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/yugioh/images/a/ad/BreakthroughSkill-SR02-EN-C-1E.png/revision/latest?cb=20160706183604)

Card can be banished from anywhere, be it your field, your hand, your graveyard (your discard pile), or your deck. Cards may be banished facedown if a card tells you to do so. You may not look at your opponent's facedown banished cards, but you may look at your own.

For any further information, see the wiki article on this topic: [Banish | Yu-Gi-Oh! Wikia](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Banish)

Answer (score 1):

"Banish a card from the graveyard" means that you choose a card from the graveyard to banish. The card you have banished is disintegrated through the vortex. The graveyard is a player's discard pile, banish means to remove a card from the game, while vortex means any card with vortex in it's name.

See article: [Banish](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Banish) on yu-gi-oh wikia.
Fandom powered by wikia.

Comment: While this answer looks correct, I think it would be a lot more useful if it included one sentence summaries of what "graveyard" and "banish" mean, e.g. "the graveyard is your discard pile" and "a banished card is removed from the game permanently" (if those are accurate? I don't actually play yu-gi-oh)

Comment: @BenjaminCosman a more accurate definition of the graveyard would be used cards that are not in the hand or on the field anymore, and banished doesnt neccessarily mean removed from the game permanently anymore as there are lots of cards to interact with the banished zone nowadays

Comment: Makes sense, that's why I was encouraging the author to edit rather than writing an answer myself.

Comment: @BenjaminCosman i know, i was just making you aware considering you werent 100% on the facts

Answer (score 0):

Banish, in the older terms, "remove from play", is another place a card can go to besides graveyard, and can only be brought back if a card specifically says so. Also, they are generally banished face-up unless cards that banish says banish face-down, and face-down, neither player can see unless the effects that banished them says otherwise.